# How can I check if an attractor is strange?

Tags: javascript, strange-attractor

Lately I learned a bit about strange attractors, and I created the following programm in JS:

```js
var ctx, clock, width, height, pixSize;
var x,y,a,b,c,d;

window.onload = function(){
 start();
};

function start(random=true){
 window.cancelAnimationFrame(clock);
 if(random){
  a = 6*Math.random()-3;
  b = 6*Math.random()-3;
  c = 2*Math.random()-0.5;
  d = 2*Math.random()-0.5;
 }
 canvasSetup();
 clearCanvas();
 x = Math.random()-Math.random();
 y = Math.random()-Math.random();
 clock = requestAnimationFrame(main);
}


function save(){
 var text = JSON.stringify({
  a:a,
  b:b,
  c:c,
  d:d
 });
 window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C", text);
}

function load(){
 var input = JSON.parse(window.prompt("Import Save:"));
 a = input.a;
 b = input.b;
 c = input.c;
 d = input.d;
 start(false);
}

function canvasSetup(){
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 width = window.innerWidth-5;
 height = window.innerHeight-5;
 canvas.width = width;
 canvas.height = height;
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var min = Math.min(width,height);
 var scale = min/4;
 ctx.translate(width/2, height/2);
 ctx.scale(scale, scale);
 pixSize = 1/scale/2;
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
}

function clearCanvas(){
 ctx.save();
 ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
 ctx.restore();
}

function main(){
 for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
  var xnew = Math.sin(y*b)+c*Math.sin(x*b);
  var ynew = Math.sin(x*a)+d*Math.sin(y*a);
  x = xnew;
  y = ynew;
  plot(x,y,"rgb(50,5,1)");
 }
 clock = requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

function plot(x,y,color="white"){
 ctx.fillStyle = color;
 ctx.fillRect(x,-y,pixSize,pixSize);
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 font-family: Consolas;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#buttons{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Strange Attractor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="rules.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div align="center">
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
   <button onclick="start()">New Attractor</button><br>
   <button onclick="save()">Save</button><br>
   <button onclick="load()">Load</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

It's taking 4 random Parameters (a,b,c,d) and uses the formular

```
var xnew = Math.sin(y*b)+c*Math.sin(x*b);
var ynew = Math.sin(x*a)+d*Math.sin(y*a);
x = xnew;
y = ynew;
```

for the new point. In some cases this indeed creates a fancy strange sttractor:[image]

But in other cases I only get a single line or a few points. Is there a simple way to look at the parameters and find out, if the attrator they create will be strange?

I know, that I could save a bunch of values, compare them with each other and test in that way, if the picture might be intresting, but I'd love a different solution...

I hope you can help :)

EDIT:
To look at speccific values you can simply use the save and load buttons in the js sketch above...

Comment: I tried looking at things like `console.log(a, b, c, d); console.log(a-b, b-c, c-d, a-c, a-d, b-c, b-d, c-d);` but I wasn't able to spot a pattern. Interesting problem.

Comment: Instead of console.log() you can also simply use the save button I added... It gives you a,b,c and d in JSON format.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I added the console.log()'s so I could run a bunch and see the outputs with less clicks.