# Color-Scales depending on how often a point gets drawn (JS Canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

Lately I created a project involving drawing a lot of points on a canvas to plot a strange attractor. The details of this project aren't really relevant, but if you want to see it in action, go here: [How can I check if an attractor is strange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016297/how-can-i-check-if-an-attractor-is-strange)

The problem I was encountering is the following: How can I draw a point on a canvas, whose color depends on the color, that was already there? In other words: How do I implement a color scale that depends on that number of times, a specific point has been colored?

I actually found a way, but I'm not convinced if it's the best. Here is how it works:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(50,5,1)";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,size,size);
```

It simply adds to the color that is already there. This can already look pretty good: [image]

But there are also a lot of restrictions when using this method:

- I can't get a colorchange from green to red for example
- Using this method on a white background is impossible
- I can't create a colorscale that includes more than to "fixed points", like for example red->green->blue

Maybe you know methods that work better than mine...

Comment: What if – instead of drawing the points directly to canvas – you'd save the attractor points into a 3d array (x, y, data points per coordinate). You'd then determine the max/min value for the entire array, and finally draw each pixel to a canvas, while mapping the amount of points to a gradient.

Comment: Here's an example implementation https://jsfiddle.net/m58u1vkv/2/

Comment: @thykka The problem with that is, that I don't draw points only exactly on specific x,y values, but also in between...

Comment: you can still do that. Scale the coordinates up first, round them into integers, save them into the array and when you're drawing the array, scale the coordinates down again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to track hits per pixel to implement a function that would allow you to change picture color, rather than just luminosity or redness. As suggested above, you should use a multi-dimensional array to track hits per pixel.

```
var canvasPixels = [];
for (var y = 0; y < 1000; y++) {
    canvasPixels[y] = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
    canvasPixels[y][x] = 0;
  }
}
```

There are any number of things you can do if you apply the color math yourself. Here I'm using a color sine wave.

```
function getColor(hits) {

  var frequency = 0.3;
  var r = Math.round(Math.sin(frequency*hits + 0) * 127 + 128);
  var g = Math.round(Math.sin(frequency*hits + 2) * 127 + 128);
  var b = Math.round(Math.sin(frequency*hits + 4) * 127 + 128);

  return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}
```

Then, you just use this function when drawing to cycle through the rainbow.

```
canvasPixels[y][x]++;
ctx.fillStyle = getColor(canvasPixels[y][x]);
ctx.fillRect(x,y,size,size);
```